# fragments best practices

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello I'm new to the android ecosystem and wanted to inquire about best practices when it comes to defining a fragments content

currently I'm opening a connection to my database aswell as initialising onClick listeners in my fragment's `onCreateView` but I'm also aware that there exists `onViewCreated` and `onCreate` similar to a regular activity, while I'm familiar with where everything is placed in an activity, I'm not as sure about fragments, can someone help me out?

-thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `onCreateView()`

This is the place where you initialize your views (`findViewById()`) / attach listeners to them.

From android docs:

> Called to have the fragment instantiate its user interface view

#### `onCreate()`

It's better to move the code that connects to the database here - code that doesn't depend on UI elements.

You can read more in the official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).